# how to find currently running thread in boost?

Tags: c++, boost

The problem that I have is with lines (1), (2), and (3) in the snippet.

1. How can I pass the thread object of the currently running thread?
2. How can I perform the context switching without using boost::condition_variable ? (eg. `sleep(for ever)`)
3. How can I re-run the thread?

```
1   void wait()
2   {
3       if( some condition)
4       {
5           queue.enqueue( "current thread object" ); (1)
6           boost::this_thread ( // context switch ) (2)
7       }
8   }
9
10  void signal()
11  {
12      boost::thread myThread = queue.dequeue();
13      myThread.run(); (3)
14  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't understand why you don't just use `boost::condition_variable` or `boost::thread_pool` (depending on what you want to do).

There is something called [`boost::context`](http://lists.boost.org/boost-announce/2012/01/0343.php) that is being reviewed for addition into boost, which I think does what you want.

Something along the lines of:

```
void wait()
{
    if( some condition)
    {
        myContext->suspend(); // (2)
        queue.enqueue(std::move(myContext)); // (1)
    }
}

void signal()
{
      std::unique_ptr<boost::context> myContext = queue.dequeue();
      myContext->resume(); // (3)
}
```